# uglify Invalid hex-character pattern in string

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

Here is my code:

```
var xxx = '\u{1F393}'
```

When I use gulp-uglify, I get the following error message:

> 'Invalid hex-character pattern in string'

Comment: This does not give an error, but emoji is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that your gulp-uglify doesn't support [unicode point escapes](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#escape-sequences). For this emoji, you could write it as its functionally identical surrogate pair `\ud83c\udf93`.

```js
console.log('\u{1F393}');
console.log('\ud83c\udf93');
```

Here is a simple script to help you convert out the emoji's into their surrogate pairs:

```js
const str = '';
const str2 = '\u{1F393}';

function getEscaped(str) {
  var ret = '';
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    var code = str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);

    ret += '\\u' + code;
  }
  
  return ret;
}

const result = getEscaped(str);
console.log(result);
console.log(eval(`"${result}"`));
console.log(getEscaped(str2));
```